# How to consolidate 2 database calls

Tags: wordpress

I'm not experienced with WordPress so please excuse me if the question is stupid.

I have a custom template page that displays record information obtained from database. This page also call `get_header()` to generate the header part of the page.

I want that the page title (in `HEAD HTML`) will display some of the record information also.

What is the best way to do this, the "WordPress way", with 1 database query?

Currently I execute 2 identical database queries: one in `add_filter('wp_title', myfunc) @ function.php` and the other in my custom template PHP. This duplication looks wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured that out... I guess I have to use [global wordpress database connection (`$wpdb`)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)